# Model Binding collections in ASP.NET MVC with hidden controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hihi,

Having trouble model binding with this class (the following concrete, not the abstract).
Ignore the basic properties, its the Lists that I'm interested in binding.

```
public abstract class MessageModel
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public const int DefaultIdValue = Int32.MinValue;

    public List<LinkModel> Linked { get; set; }
    public List<LinkModel> NotLinked { get; set; }

    protected MessageModel()
    {
        Id = DefaultIdValue;
        Linked = new List<LinkModel>();
        NotLinked = new List<LinkModel>();
    }

    protected MessageModel(string tag, string message):this()
    {
        Tag = tag;
        Message = message;
    }
}

public class TextModel:MessageModel
{
        public int TextId { get; set; }

        public TextModel()
        {
                TextId = DefaultIdValue;
        }
}
```

This is the submission I get on the server side on submit (formatted for sanity):

```
Tag=
&Message=
&NotLinked.index=35fda83a053645e6809bbb8b0ea00103
&NotLinked.index=14c2e286e28b4c9d8f889fb3eb437e5f
&NotLinked.%5b35fda83a053645e6809bbb8b0ea00103%5d.RecipientId=1
&NotLinked.%5b35fda83a053645e6809bbb8b0ea00103%5d.RecipientName=Bob+Biggins
&NotLinked.%5b14c2e286e28b4c9d8f889fb3eb437e5f%5d.RecipientId=2
&NotLinked.%5b14c2e286e28b4c9d8f889fb3eb437e5f%5d.RecipientName=Billy+Oswold
&Submit=Submit
```

When the function is called that accepts that model the NotLinked collection is set to null. D:

The (relevant) output html looks like this (im trying to "faux" bind to:

```
<ol> and <li>
```

with jQuery doing the work of moving stuff around)

```
<div id="NotLinkedContainer">
    <ol id="NotLinked" name="NotLinked" style="width: 500px;height: 200px">
        <li value="1">Bob Biggins
            <input id="NotLinked_index" name="NotLinked.index" type="hidden" value="a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b" />
            <input id="NotLinked__a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b__RecipientId" name="NotLinked.[a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b].RecipientId" type="hidden" value="1" />
            <input id="NotLinked__a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b__RecipientName" name="NotLinked.[a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b].RecipientName" type="hidden" value="Bob Biggins" />
        </li>
        <li value="2">Billy Oswold
            <input id="NotLinked_index" name="NotLinked.index" type="hidden" value="d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7" />
            <input id="NotLinked__d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7__RecipientId" name="NotLinked.[d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7].RecipientId" type="hidden" value="2" />
            <input id="NotLinked__d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7__RecipientName" name="NotLinked.[d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7].RecipientName" type="hidden" value="Billy Oswold" />
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Haven't done this sort of complex binding before so I'm at a loss at the simple mistake I've probably made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the dot notation before the brackets and since this isn't a dictionary, but a list, you need to use indices, not keys. The correct syntax for a list in a razor view should look more like this:

```
<div id="NotLinkedContainer">
    <ol id="NotLinked" name="NotLinked" style="width: 500px;height: 200px">
        <li value="1">Bob Biggins
            <input id="NotLinked_index" name="NotLinked.index" type="hidden" value="a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b" />
            <input id="NotLinked__a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b__RecipientId" name="NotLinked[0].RecipientId" type="hidden" value="1" />
            <input id="NotLinked__a0ab331bee2a461084b686e13a87090b__RecipientName" name="NotLinked[0].RecipientName" type="hidden" value="Bob Biggins" />
        </li>
        <li value="2">Billy Oswold
            <input id="NotLinked_index" name="NotLinked.index" type="hidden" value="d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7" />
            <input id="NotLinked__d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7__RecipientId" name="NotLinked[1].RecipientId" type="hidden" value="2" />
            <input id="NotLinked__d7d294d3174c4bd98d583e92010359e7__RecipientName" name="NotLinked[1].RecipientName" type="hidden" value="Billy Oswold" />
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Here is an article that covers what you are attempting to do:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: It was the . before the [ that was the problem. Thanks! Also indicies are not required as long as the ids all match. :)